# Why is this website not able to be scraped using bs4?

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape each month and the specific release notes, but I can't seem to get anything. It looks like it's markdown. I've never had trouble with any site before. Any ideas?

https://central.xero.com/s/article/Xero-Releases

```js
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
}

url = 'https://central.xero.com/s/article/Xero-Releases'
res = requests.get(url, verify=True, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.title)

texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The site is using Javascript to get its actual content after it was loaded.

You are currently doing a HTTP-Request on the site which will only return the content of the initial HTML-file, but can't execute Javascript to get the actual content.

Comment: Is there any way to scrape the content if it is using js to get the content?